# Stuck in hardware check (USB Audio)

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 desktop version on my computer but I can't pass the hardware check. It always gets stuck on following lines:

```
Product: USB Audio
Manufacturer: Generic
```

I'm also attaching the picture of the screen bellow.

[Hardware check never passes this point!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33yNE.jpg)

I can easily install Windows 10 without any issues.

Configuration bellow:

```
motherboard: ASRock TRX40 CREATOR
cpu: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3960X
gpu: Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
```

I suspect it might be the motherboard issue as it clearly states support for Windows 10 at ASRock website. But I don't expect that to block linux all together.

Please let me know if you need to have any additional information.

Thank you so much for any help or advice

Comment: Unplug ALL USB devices except the mouse/keyboard and see if it gets farther.

Comment: Make and model of the computer? Please obtain model number from the serial number sticker; other 'model numbers' elsewhere on the PC are likely marketing buzzwords and don't provide useful info. If this is a desktop with no model number there, make and model of the motherboard and video card would be helpful. Please click [edit]] and save that information into the question; please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the the question. I tried to install it without any extra devices in any USB port but it still does it...

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to check your current BIOS version. See https://www.asrock.com/support/index.asp?cat=BIOS for newer BIOS. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, Thanks for your advice. Not sure how to run that command as I can't even run Ubuntu without installation but I did check the Bios version in my current Windows system. it's: "American Megatrends Inc. P1.10, 30/10/2019" It doesn't look like any newer updates for my motherboard are available yet, apart of beta release: https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/TRX40%20Creator/index.asp#BIOS

Comment: @Jirka Good job on the BIOS check. Commands like dmidecode can be run from the `terminal` when booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. In your BIOS, is USB set to legacy?